# VBA Problem with vlookup from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to do vlookup functions from the scope vl1, where the key that connects will be vl2 to wb.Sheets("C_3300").Value("O28") . But i got error. "Unable to get the WorksheetFunction Vlookup property" . Where am I making a mistake

```
Dim vl1 As Range
Dim vl2 As Range
Set vl1 = wbMe.Sheets("res_mat").Range("A10:B13")
Set vl2 = wb.Sheets("C_3300").Value("B28")

wb.Sheets("C_3300").Value("O28") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(vl2, vl1, 2, 0)
```

Comment: `wb.Sheets("C_3300").Value("O28")` should probably be `wb.Sheets("C_3300").range("O28").value`

Comment: @Warcupine its working ! thanks :)